# What should be the correct inital value for redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I wanted to create 'add to cart' functionality using Redux, so I have defined a reducer function which accepts a state and action, where state is provided a default value.

```
export const defaultValue= {
  products: [
    {
      id: "",
      title: "",
      description: "",
      image: "",
      price: 0,
      amount: 0,
    },
  ]
};

export const manageCart = (
  state = defaultValue,
  action: { type: string; payload: any}
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionConstants.ADD_TO_CARTS:
      {
       // ADD to card
      }
  break;
    case actionConstants.REMOVE_FROM_CART: {
      // Remove from card     
     }
 default:
      return state;
}
}
```

[image]
So by default I'm seeing this blank product on my cart which is messing up my logic moving further. Since it is mandatory to provide initial value to the state, what should i do differently to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So by default I'm seeing this blank product on my cart which is messing up my logic moving further.

Because you are passing that blank product in the default state!

Just pass an empty array instead

```
export const defaultValue= {
  products: []
};
```

Comment: I'm using TypeScript here, so if I try to access any value from state (state.products.amount) i get 'Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'never'', so I have to provide it with value

Comment: Anyway you won't be able to access state.products.amount because products is an array. state.products.map(({ id, title, amount }) => { ... })

Comment: Sure. but won't it throw an error 'Property 'products' does not exist on type 'never[]' because it don't know what product is.

Comment: @ArpitMishra If you are using Typescript, then you should define an interface for the state!

Comment: @MurhafSousli Yep, that fixed the solution.

Comment: @ArpitMishra Nice, can you mark my fix as the answer?